# Getting a reference to Ragdoll joints in Ragdoll prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have a 3D ragdoll created from a Dummy model and the ragdoll prefab.
When I press play, this ragdoll falls on the ground as a ragdoll is supposed to do, so I have created the ragdoll part correctly

I am trying to programmatically move some of the joints, such as bend the knee or rotate the shoulder, up to the limits allowed by the ragdoll or human body.

The script is assigned to the top level parent

First, I would like to get a reference for each joint.
Do I need to create a member variable for each one such as `public CharacterJoint head;`? Or is there an easier way of accessing them from parent

Next, I would like to know how to actuate the joint from within the `CharacterJoint` component.
When I click on one of the body parts, I can see a `CharacterJoint` component is assigned to it, but I do not see a field where I can enter the current joint angle.

How can I set the joint angle from C#?
And what about 2 DOF joints such as the shoulder, can I set the joint position and angle from C#?

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, use the **[Configurable Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConfigurableJoint.html)** instead of **Character Joint** if you want to control the joint's rotation using physical force.

Then you can create the a `Dictionary<string, ConfigurableJoint> allJoints` to pair the joint name with joint and access joint with its name using `shoulderJoint = allJoints["shoulder"]`, or dictionary with name and custom class pair if you have more parameters about each joint.

Last [set the target rotation for each joint](https://gist.github.com/mstevenson/4958837):

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class ConfigurableJointExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a joint's targetRotation to match a given local rotation.
    /// The joint transform's local rotation must be cached on Start and passed into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetTargetRotationLocal (this ConfigurableJoint joint, Quaternion targetLocalRotation, Quaternion startLocalRotation)
    {
        if (joint.configuredInWorldSpace) {
            Debug.LogError ("SetTargetRotationLocal should not be used with joints that are configured in world space. For world space joints, use SetTargetRotation.", joint);
        }
        SetTargetRotationInternal (joint, targetLocalRotation, startLocalRotation, Space.Self);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a joint's targetRotation to match a given world rotation.
    /// The joint transform's world rotation must be cached on Start and passed into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetTargetRotation (this ConfigurableJoint joint, Quaternion targetWorldRotation, Quaternion startWorldRotation)
    {
        if (!joint.configuredInWorldSpace) {
            Debug.LogError ("SetTargetRotation must be used with joints that are configured in world space. For local space joints, use SetTargetRotationLocal.", joint);
        }
        SetTargetRotationInternal (joint, targetWorldRotation, startWorldRotation, Space.World);
    }
    
    static void SetTargetRotationInternal (ConfigurableJoint joint, Quaternion targetRotation, Quaternion startRotation, Space space)
    {
        // Calculate the rotation expressed by the joint's axis and secondary axis
        var right = joint.axis;
        var forward = Vector3.Cross (joint.axis, joint.secondaryAxis).normalized;
        var up = Vector3.Cross (forward, right).normalized;
        Quaternion worldToJointSpace = Quaternion.LookRotation (forward, up);
        
        // Transform into world space
        Quaternion resultRotation = Quaternion.Inverse (worldToJointSpace);
        
        // Counter-rotate and apply the new local rotation.
        // Joint space is the inverse of world space, so we need to invert our value
        if (space == Space.World) {
            resultRotation *= startRotation * Quaternion.Inverse (targetRotation);
        } else {
            resultRotation *= Quaternion.Inverse (targetRotation) * startRotation;
        }
        
        // Transform back into joint space
        resultRotation *= worldToJointSpace;
        
        // Set target rotation to our newly calculated rotation
        joint.targetRotation = resultRotation;
    }
}
```